# selecting first match in google maps static when location returns multiple results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using Google Maps static interface to show maps in my web application. I am using address to pinpoint place (example: Street name, Post-code City, Country), using PHP to generate maps embed URL. This works great but sometimes some addresses return multiple results and maps drop multiple PINs (Place A, B, C, etc...) at the same address!

Example 1: address is one place -> everything is OK, marker is displayed with place address
[http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Skrita+ulica+5,+2000+Maribor,+Slovenija+(OAZA MIRU)&f=q&source=s_q&hl=sl&ie=UTF8&z=15&t=m&iwloc=addr&output=embed](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Skrita%20ulica%205,%202000%20Maribor,%20Slovenija%20%28OAZA%20MIRU%29&f=q&source=s_q&hl=sl&ie=UTF8&z=15&t=m&iwloc=addr&output=embed)

Example 2: address returns multiple places and marker with place name does not show
[http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Ulica+Eve+Lovše+1,+2000+Maribor,+Slovenija+(Restavracija+in+Pizzeria+%22MISTERIUM%22+Mercator+Center+)&f=q&source=s_q&hl=sl&ie=UTF8&z=15&t=m&iwloc=addr&output=embed](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Ulica%20Eve%20Lov%C5%A1e%201,%202000%20Maribor,%20Slovenija%20%28Restavracija%20in%20Pizzeria%20%22MISTERIUM%22%20Mercator%20Center%20%29&f=q&source=s_q&hl=sl&ie=UTF8&z=15&t=m&iwloc=addr&output=embed)

Is there a possibility to auto select for-example the first place on the matched address and show a marker like in Example 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `num` parameter determines how many results to show. Add `num=1` to the URL to restrict the results to just one. [Reference](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters#Search_Mode). (You can even specify `num=0` but that seems a bit pointless)

NB: If the URL returns more than one result, it's because the search algorithm can't be certain of the right result based on your `q=` string. Restricting the output to just the first one may not produce the result you want.

Comment: This worked for limiting result shown on the map, but it broke what is displayed as the title in the marker. If I set the `num` parameter to 1 (`&num=1`) it automatically displays that place's title instead the title I set in querystring. Any idea why it doesn't take the title I set in query string between () - `(Restavracija+in+Pizzeria+%22MISTERIUM%22+Mercator+Center+)`? See my map URLs above. The title in the marker should be the string I set between () in `q` parameter.

Comment: It's because there is more than one result and Google Maps doesn't know which to apply your text to. All you are doing is restricting how many results are *shown*: you are not restricting the number found by the query. I did warn the results might not be what you want.

Comment: So I can not force maps to show a desired message in the marker bubble? There are many results (businesses) at this address but the one I need is not in Google maps directory? I want a market at this address but show the right business name inside the bubble. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The only way of *ensuring* you get markers looking exactly how you want is to use the API. The Google Maps site provides a certain amount of control, but not the amount you get with the API.

Comment: Ok looks like I am going to have to go with JS API